# get_circuits() of Stem library returns an empty list

Tags: tor, stem

When I execute controller.get_circuits(), I get an empty list. How could this be?

```
with stem.control.Controller.from_port(port=9151) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()
  controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM) # get new tor identity
  circs = controller.get_circuits()

  for circ in controller.get_circuits():
    print(circ.id)
  print(len(circs))
  print(circs[1].id)
```

Comment: I have the same issue.

Comment: The circuits won't be built until used.  You need to issue a request over Tor in order to establish them.  Make a dummy request in between NEWNYM and get_circuits and you'll see them.